# How can I access a [vba] function from a different [excel] workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pretty simple, but frequently used function, However I generally need to use it on new excel docs. To manually add in the code for the function to each workbook will be defeating the purpose of the function... Is there any way to access a function that is not stored in the active workbook?

See the code below if it might help you understand what I need:

```
Function potential(ByVal Volume As Double, ByVal Original As Double, Optional ByVal Better As Double = 0) As Double
    If Better = 0 Then Exit Function
    potential = (Original - Better) * Volume
End Function
```

Comment: Why not just use an XLAM Add-In? - It would make life much more simple.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this web page [Create and save all your macros in a single workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-66c97ab3-11c2-44db-b021-ae005a9bc790)